# flask socketIO multiprocessing Value

Tags: flask, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I am attempting to use multiprocessing Value to update a data element with a
multiprocessed function. The data Value is not updating more than once.  I have read the following pages and the other questions: 
I wonder if the Flask app is interferring…?

```
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent
http://timmyreilly.azurewebsites.net/flask-socketio-and-more/
https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/356
```

This is a flask, wtf, socketio, bootstrap, python 2.7 application. 
All works except for the data Value share.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.urandom(24)
Bootstrap(app)
socketio = SocketIO(app)
mp_date = Value('f', 0.0, lock=False)  

if __name__ == '__main__':
operation_run = multiprocessing.Process(target=sys_operations,args=((parent_conn, child_conn),True, mp_date)) 

operation_run.start()
socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', debug=True,use_reloader=False)

In the multiprocessed function 
def orerry_operations(pipe, first_run, mp_date):
….
    mp_date.value=moving_date  #this is the update that does not work,
                moving_date is a float
    print 'mp_date obj: ' + str(mp_date)
    print 'mp_date  ' + str(mp_date.value)
    print 'moving_date  ' + str(moving_date)

the print results are:
mp_date obj: c_float(581948928.0)
mp_date  581948928.0
moving_date  581948957.797

mp_date obj: c_float(581948928.0)
mp_date  581948928.0
moving_date  581948959.814

mp_date obj: c_float(581948992.0)
mp_date  581948992.0
moving_date  581948961.83
```

As you can see, the mp_date Value is not updating. 
It seems to set the first time, 
then not subsequently.
I do not join as the function runs continuously.
    Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify at the beginning of your function orerry_operations:

```
global mp_date
```